# IVP Separable Equation where given answer not correct?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

So I'm working on the following problem:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}, y=1, x=0
$$

To me this appears as a separable first order differential equation, so I separate it into g(x) and h(y) as follows:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}=\frac{1+y^2}{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$ 
and this allows us to use the general solution of:
$$
\int\frac{dy}{h(y)} = \int g(x)dx + c
$$
which in my example results in:
$$
\int\frac{dy}{1+y^2} = \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx + c
$$
Which straight away we can apply the basic integral for arctan:
$$
arctan(y) = arctan(x) + c
$$
At this point I multiplied both sides by tan to get y = f(x).  From there working out c is just a matter of substituting our original values for x and y, I believe.  I'll go no further at this point as I've done much of this on paper, but no matter what I try, I cannot arrive at the solution given in the notes.

The answer given in the notes is:
$$
y=\frac{1+x}{1-x}
$$
At this point I also tried plugging the equation into some online calculators, and they arrived at a similar solution, this being wolframs answer:
$$
y(x) = tan(arctan(x) + π/4)
$$

I'd be very thankful if someone could poke me in the right direction on this one, are the two answers somehow equivalent, or have a made a foolish error?  Regardless, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\tan(a+b) = \frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1-\tan a\cdot\tan b}.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how I can apply this to my result.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe I do, one moment.

Comment: You are suggesting that $tan(arctan(y)) = \frac{tan(arctan(x) + tan(c))}{1-tan(arctan(x)) + tan(c)}$?

Comment: No. You have $\arctan(y) = \arctan(x)+\arctan(1)$. Now, apply $\tan$ on both sides and use the formula for the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that is what I have put but not simplified or substituted 1 for c.  But I understand.  Thank you again.

Comment: Nope, it's not. What you wrote is nonsense, sorry. When you apply the formula you will see that $y = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$.

Comment: Lol, ok I'm sorry, I'll work this through on paper and see what comes out, clearly I'm still getting used to Mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* When you multiplied both sides by $\tan{},$ what happened to the constant?

Comment: This resulted in $y=tan(arctan(x)+c)$, which I cannot further simplify, (save to $x+tan(c)$ I believe.

Comment: @WilliamSlater No, it doesn't simplify to that. I believe you now know what it simplifies to since someone above has shown you how to resolve the tangent of a sum.

Comment: How do you multiply with a function (not with a function value?) You can apply or compose functions, perhaps also concatenate or (en-)chain.

Comment: @LutzL Use your favourite language. I went with OP's language because it's also right -- even though they might not have thought of it they way I did.